# 403 permission denied nginx, vagrant, centos

Tags: nginx, permissions, vagrant, centos7

I am having trouble setting up my basic vagrant VM to serve some content.
Nginx is saying it does not have permission to serve the index for my project folder. I have tried setting all permissions to 777 for the project directory and changing the Nginx user to vagrant.

I am unsure but from reading around apparently SELinux may be causing issues as it is enabled on the server and there are lines in the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` like this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1471185070.388:854): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=4653 comm="nginx" path="/var/www/project/index.html" dev="0:37" ino=12161210 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=file
```

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name knifesprinter.local;
    index index.html;

    location /{
        root /var/www/project;
        autoindex on;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

And all permissions to `/var/www/project` are allowed. Does someone know what the deal is here? I have setup a few servers with Nginx before but not on CentOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yip, definitely a SELinux issue. Please, please don't disable SELinux by setting enforce to 0. You can allow Nginx access using `audit2allow`. This will generate a policy for you which you can apply using `semodule`. You'll need to run the following as `root`. You could sudo the commands, but you'll encounter an issue with `semodule`.

Firstly, if your system doesn't have `audit2allow`:

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

Next, create the policy:

```
grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
```

Then apply the policy:

```
semodule -i mypol.pp
```

It's worthwhile noting that `audit2allow` may give more access than needed. If you're concered about that, you may also use [restorecon or chcon](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=selinux&f=5) in certain cases.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it didn't feel right just disabling this completely, using the grep http wasn't working for some reason however i had to use  audit2allow -a -M after a page load.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. Might be useful in future.

Comment: Want to add you +100 plus. Thank you for solution!

Comment: @DenisSavenko, thanks :) Strange seeing people still having these issues 2 years later. Anyway, glad it helped.